# Removing Wine completely

Tags: 14.04, wine, uninstall

Hoping someone can help me here with this issue I'm having. Wine isn't working on my Ubuntu 14.04LTS so I want to completely remove it and install from the software manager

Code I'm using is as follows

```
sudo apt-get purge wine
```

Which shows

```
wine            wine1.6         wine1.6-amd64   wine1.6-i386    wine-gecko2.21  wine-gecko2.34  wine-mono0.0.8  wine-mono4.5.4  winetricks
```

So When I go to unistall using

```
sudo apt-get remove wine1.6 --purge --no-install-recommends
```

It uninstalls wine1.6 all fine but also then installs another version

```
The following NEW packages will be installed


wine1.8 wine1.8-amd64 wine1.8-i386:i386
```

My question is how can I prevent wine1.8 from being installed as I want wine removed completely. Sorry if this is really simple I'm new to ubuntu and learning slowly

Thanks,
*Youlethal*

Comment: Try updatedb command and then try to see if the which command would return the some result or not

Comment: I'm voting for the duplicate, but I'm curious - why are you using `--no-install-recommends` for an uninstall process?

Answer (score 4):

I think your first command is only purging the wine package, which is just a dependency for the others.

```
sudo apt-get purge "^wine.*"
```

should purge every package on your system starting with the word 'wine'.

Note that apt-get uses regular expressions for pattern matching, hence the ^ and .*

Comment: This works and is safe, but you don't actually need the `.*` at the end (and, without it, the quotes become optional). That is, you can just use `sudo apt-get purge ^wine`. The presence of `^` is sufficient to cause the argument to be interpreted as a regular expression, and when `apt` or `apt-get` interprets an argument as a regular expression, it matches it anywhere in the package name. That's why you need `^`--to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the match to the start of the package name. The regex doesn't need to match the entire package name, just any part of it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply running

```
sudo apt remove --purge wine*
```

should remove the wine packages and not result in any additional installations.

**Sidenotes**

- <kbd>*</kbd> is acting as wildcard here
- `apt` and `apt-get` are similar commands - while they are not 1:1 the same. `apt` seems to be the future.
- `--purge` results in removing the user-related configs as well and not just the package itself

Comment: *Don't do this!* See [Why does apt removes unwanted packages when giving * as suffix?](https://askubuntu.com/q/431604) The `purge` or `remove` action with an argument like `wine*`, `wine\*`, or `'wine*'` removes way more than you might think. It removes every package with `win` anywhere in its name (not `wine`, `win`--as `wine*` is treated as a regex and `e*` means "zero or more `e`s") and every package that depends directly or indirectly on any of those packages. This often breaks an Ubuntu system very badly, preventing it from being used for much of anything until it is fixed or reinstalled.

Comment: So wine+ will do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
purge remove
```

will remove about everything regarding the package *packagename*, but not the dependencies established during installation.

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove [packagename]
```

This will remove the package along with the configuration files and dependencies.

You may like to have a walk through following links:

[How to completely remove any program and its installation files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711793/how-to-completely-remove-any-program-and-its-installation-files/711837#711837)

[What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after conducting

```
sudo apt-get remove wine
```

Wine still appear in a dash. So I tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge wine
```

Which gave me an output:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: (...)
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

So when you get to this point, then you can run this command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

When I did that, wine disappeared from the dash.

Comment: That's effectively the same as [Dhaval's answer](/a/771292/175814). `apt-get purge <PACKAGE> && apt-get autoremove` is equivalent to `apt-get purge --auto-remove <PACKAGE>`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I think this is a different, nicer, easier, less error prone way. *(a)* In practice when one knows one needs autoremoval, it is often because one has *already* run an `apt` or `apt-get` command with the `remove` or `purge` action. So the method here is usually the one that is useful. *(b)* If one is unsure about whether or not one wants autoremoval, it's better to use these two separate steps. There's nothing wrong with `purge --auto-remove`--the other answer has value--but I wouldn't recommend getting in the habit of removing what one *thinks* are single packages in that way.