# How to completely remove a program?

Tags: package-management, uninstall

I have transferred to linux 3 days ago and there are so many things that I love about it but at the same time I am starting to grow tired, because majority of stuff just does not work as it is supposed to.

For example I have read that you need to execute

```
sudo apt --purge remove $packagename
```

command to remove a program and its configuration files, but it just does not work for me! I messed up with Evolution a little bit annd I want a clean install now and when I do that command and then reinstall it again, I am getting Evolution package with all my emails inside it already together with all the changes I have made of course.

So how the hell do I remove the program completely out of ubuntu system, together with it config files, installation files, JUST EVERYTHING THAT'S RELATED TO THAT SPECIFIC PROGRAM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to completely remove any program and its installation files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711793/how-to-completely-remove-any-program-and-its-installation-files)

Answer (score 2):

This is a common new-user and didn't-quite-understand-the-manual question.

`apt remove <package>` removes the application only.

- Configuration (/etc) is NOT removed.
- Personal data (/home) is NOT removed.

`apt purge <package>` removes the application and configuration.

- Personal data (/home) is NOT removed.

No apt command removes personal data in /home. You must delete that yourself.

Comment: What is meant by configuration here then? and what exactly I should delete in order to remove that app's configuration and settings I have made on that package?

Comment: You must locate, within your /home dir, the `.evolution`, `.config/evolution`, and `.cache/evolution` directories. There may be others. Delete them. That's where your e-mail (which is *your personal data*) is stored.

Comment: Thanks. 

Command {sudo ls -lRa . |grep .evolution}

helped as well!

Answer (score 0):

As the answer by @user535733 said, it's not removed from /home. If you messed up the installation, you'd be better off reinstalling ubuntu. Don't worry, it happens

Comment: it's not a solution. so do you mean if I change some app settings and dont know how to revert them I should reinstall my system everytime? its nonsense

Comment: @shiu'sho no no no that's not what I mean. I mean that if ubuntu is unusable because of this you should reinstall. I also said don't reinstall unless removing it's files from /home causes you to break your install or something.