# Whats the best way of deleting files and applications

Tags: apt, package-management

I've been wondering for a while now what the optimal way of deleting and removing packages and software is.
What I always do is `sudo apt remove package` and straight after I do `sudo apt autoremove` to get rid of the redundant files.

My question to you is: Is there a better way than the one I'm using and if so what is it?

Comment: "Best" is a matter of opinion. Your way is correct, sensible, and easy to understand. Optionally you can merge the lines (`sudo apt autoremove [--purge] package`) and there are a few variations upon that. But that doesn't make them "best". Generally, "best" is the way that YOU understand and can remember how to use properly. "Best" might be different for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Difference Between \`apt-get purge\` and \`apt-get remove\`?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231562/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-get-purge-and-apt-get-remove). Also: https://askubuntu.com/q/711793

Answer (score 2):

If said software saves settings then simply removing it often do not remove the settings folder.

Instead you can use: `sudo apt purge package`

Comment: Thanks a lot of the reply! One question however. Does purge also act as remove?

Comment: Yes, it does. It uninstalls the software plus the settings.

Comment: That's actually great lol,thanks a lot :-)

Comment: If it was useful you can accept the answer.