# Oracle VM Virtual Box Doesn't start

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, lubuntu

I had read former questions about this topic but didn't find something similar o a thing which solves my problem.

I'm using Lubuntu 16.04

Trying to run VirtualBox for Windows 8 or 10, I had downloaded Oracle VM VirtualBox from the Official Webpage. With i386 package.

When I click on the shortcut nothing happens.

Please help.

Comment: Run it from the terminal and [edit] the question with the output.

Comment: Hello, @M.Becerra I solved. I think It was the installation package. When I open the properties of the icon it shows 0 bytes of information, was strange, so I uninstalled completely and installed again but this time from the terminal and it works, the windows of VM opens. Now I would like to have an icon on my desktop, any ideas? Question that help me with uninstalling: http://askubuntu.com/a/703750/632766

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall completely Oracle VM with steps in question https://askubuntu.com/a/703750/632766 (source) add autopurge when the terminal suggest you to do it. And reinstall from terminal.

Steps are:

- `sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox` **When the terminal suggest run autopurge, copy, paste and run it.**
- Run

`sudo rm ~/"VirtualBox VMs" -Rf`

`sudo rm ~/.config/VirtualBox/ -Rf`

- Install again `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`
- To open VM search in Menu>Accessories> Virtual Box