# Ubuntu 18.04 fail to install virtualbox

Tags: package-management, virtualbox, dependencies

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I saw other threads with similar errors, but no one of the answers fixed my issues.

I am trying to install virtualbox,first thing I tried is the download link for " Ubuntu 18.04 / 18.10 / Debian 10" here https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads however when I double click on it and click install, nothing happens.

So I tried to install it via the command line :

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -`
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Both commands output `OK`.

`sudo apt-get update`

Output

```
Atteint:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Atteint:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                            
Atteint:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                   
Réception de:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]                                                                                                                              
Atteint:5 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                          
Atteint:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                    
Ign:7 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                  
Atteint:8 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                                                   
Atteint:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                               
Réception de:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [204 B]
Réception de:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2 464 B]                   
Atteint:13 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian cosmic InRelease                                
91,4 ko réceptionnés en 1s (110 ko/s)                          
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
N:The file configured "non-free/binary-i386/Packages" will not be taken into account because the repository "http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian cosmic InRelease" does not support the "i386" architecture
N:The file configured "non-free/binary-i386/Packages" will not be taken into account because the repository "http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian cosmic InRelease" does not support the "i386" architecture
```

So, last two lines seems to indicate that the command is trying to update for 32 bits, but my system and OS is 64 bits :
[image: cpu_info]

And finally doing  `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.0`

Output

```
Reading package lists ... Done
Building the dependency tree
Reading status information ... Done
Some packages can not be installed. This can mean
that you asked for the impossible, or, if you use
the unstable distribution, that some packages have not yet
were created or did not come out of Incoming.
The following information should help you resolve the situation:

The following packages contain unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-6.0: Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (> = 5.6.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to fix problems, faulty packages are in "keep as is" mode.
```

I totally removed virtualbox and tried again but without success. (using the answer of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703746/how-to-completely-remove-virtualbox) question)
However when I do `sudo ps aux | grep -i "vbox"`

I have 
`louis    25612  0.0  0.0  15664  1060 pts/0    S+   13:23   0:00 grep --color=auto -i vbox`

Even after doing 
`sudo pkill VBox*`
and 
`sudo pkill vbox*`

So I don't know how to fix my problem and correctely install virtualbox

Comment: I realized that you adding `Cosmic` ppa to Bionic system ? Could you have made a mistake ? Cosmic is 18.10, while Bionic is 18.04

Comment: I guess I have to ask a new question  or search how to clean my ppa, updated from 16.04 to 18.04 and then when issues arises I try a lot of stuff I find on the web so...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `terminal`...

`cd /etc/apt` # change directory

`grep -i virtualbox sources.list` # search for virtualbox

**if found...**

- `sudo -H gedit sources.list` # edit the file
- find the line that contains `virtualbox`...
- change `deb` to `deb [arch=amd64]` and save the file.

**if NOT found...**

- `cd sources.list.d` # change to sub-directory
- `grep -i virtualbox *.list` # find the file that contains virtualbox
- edit the identified file and edit as shown above.

Comment: Thank you, sorry to not have answered you earlier. I am kind of in a rush period so I didn't have the time to try your commands this week-end, and as I said, if that solve my issue with notice when updating, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

After searching around, I found https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17970 so I did 
`sudo add-apt-repository universe`
and
`sudo apt get update`

And i successfully installed virtualbox.
However, when doing `sudo apt get update` I still have the two notices

```
N:The file configured "non-free/binary-i386/Packages" will not be taken into account because the repository "http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian cosmic InRelease" does not support the "i386" architecture
N:The file configured "non-free/binary-i386/Packages" will not be taken into account because the repository "http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian cosmic InRelease" does not support the "i386" architecture
```

so if someone find a way to fix these notices I would accept the answer